# Id и addEventListener

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Решил на своей тренировочной страничке удалить обработчики через HTML-атрибут и назначить через `addEventListener()`.

Для этого я удалит `onClick`-атрибут, назначил `id="*upButton*"`,
объявил объект:
`let **upButton** = document.getElementById("*upButton*");`

Назначил обработчик:
`upButton.addEventListener("click", up);`

И вот тут у меня возникло сомнение, а к чему я применяю обработчик?
К созданному мной объекту `**upButton**` или сразу получаю элемент по id `*upButton*` ?

Для ясности, я конечно дал разные имена своему объекту и `id`, но вопрос остался.
Как проверить через консоль, что-то не соображу?

Объясните пожалуйста, этот тонкий момент.

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос ... `upButton` - ссылка на элемент. То есть он не "перенаходит", если скажем удалить элемент и опять создать, то обработчик не будет работать, ибо элемент на который ссылается переменная был удален. Или в чем суть вопроса? И что такое: "дал разные имена своему объекту и `id`"?

Comment: Покажи код лучше, а то от твоих объяснения, вообще не понятно ничего

Comment: слегка отформатировал. 
там понятней?

а я и так показал весь код:
let upButton = document.getElementById("upButton");
upButton.addEventListener("click", up);

Comment: 10 раз перечитал...  Что означает `Решил на своей тренировочной страничке удалить обработчики через HTML-атрибут`?

Comment: А что оно такое - up ?

Answer (score 2):

Вы не "создаете" (новый) объект. Kод `document.getElementById` ищет HTML-элемент в дереве страницы и, если находит, возвращает на него ссылку. А если не находит, возвращает `null`. Ваша переменная `upButton` указывает/ссылается на уже существующий объект. Ваш код

```
let upButton = document.getElementById("upButton");
upButton.addEventListener("click", up);
```

эквивалентен

```
document.getElementById("upButton").addEventListener("click", up);
```